# javascript: how to insert data into mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have a question, how can I insert data into MySql DB with javascript?

I have the following JS Code:

```
function saveData()
{
    var table = document.getElementById('tblResult');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    i = rowCount;
    var template = "<tr> <td>"+i+"</td> <td>"+document.getElementById('ctrl_ball_size_val').value+"</td> <td style='text-align: center; background-color: lime;'>± 0.1</td> <td>"+document.getElementById('ctrl_cilindr_height_val').value+"</td> <td style='text-align: center; background-color: lime;'>± 0.1</td> <td>"+document.getElementById('stopwatch').value+"</td> <td style='text-align: center; background-color: lime;'>± 0.1</td> <td>11300</td> <td style='text-align: center; background-color: lime;'>± 0.1</td> <td>1260</td> <td style='text-align: center; background-color: lime;'>± 0.1</td> </tr>";
    $('tbody').append(template);
}
```

with this code I'm building a table with dynamic data which I got from inputs on html page.
Here is HTML code of the table:

```
<table id="tblResult" class="zebra-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th id="ID">Nr.p.k</th>
        <th>d ± △d, mm</th>
        <th style="background-color: lime;">△d, mm</th>
        <th>l ± △l, cm</th>
        <th style="background-color: lime;">△l, cm</th>
        <th>t ± △t, s</th>
        <th style="background-color: lime;">△t, s</th>
        <th>p ± △p, kg/m<sup>3</sup></th>
        <th style="background-color: lime;">△p, kg/m<sup>3</sup></th>
        <th>p<sub>1</sub> ± △p<sub>1</sub>, kg/m<sup>3</sup></th>
        <th style="background-color: lime;">△p<sub>1</sub>, kg/m<sup>3</sup></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

in which I insert this dynamic data.
So I need to insert/save all HTML table into MySQL DB, this table will be displayed on the second page, but how organize this data inserting and then displaying I don't know... Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: @showdev and can you provide some example about how to do it with Ajax?

Comment: You must use a server-side programming language to interact with a database.

Comment: @vladimir I advise POSTing the data using an HTML form and then processing and saving the data using PHP and MYSQL. However, if you absolutely need to save the data using javascript, I suggest looking into [AJAX](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php) and/or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). There are many resources and tutorials online.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it all alone via JavaScript. You need to understand the difference between client side and server sides. See your all JS code will be running on user's browser So there is no way you can provide a permanent storage at client side like mySql. You have some HTML5 storage API like webstorage, localstorage but these have constraints regarding size and others. I am not going to dive into these. So we have our database at server side. When we need some data we send a get request and fetch it. Similarly, we want to save some data we make a post request with the data. We have some service running in backend which responds to these GET and POST request and take proper actions with data sent. If you want to take a look at sample php code to interact with database. Take a look at following PHP code to interact with database.

```
<?php
/****** 5 Step Story ***********
1. Create a connection
2. Select the database
3. Fire the query
4. Use query result
5. Close the connection
*******************************/

// Step1. Create a connection
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
    die("Database connection could not be established" . mysql_error());
}

// Step2. Select the database
$db_select = mysql_select_db("widget_corp", $con);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database could not be selected" . mysql_error());
}
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Database Interaction (MySQL + PHP)  </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><center><u>Database Interation (MySQL + PHP) </u></center></h1>
    <?php
    // Step3: Querying from Database
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from subjects", $con);
      if (!$result) {
        die("Error in firing query on database" . mysql_error());
      }
   // Step4: Using query result
   /* $row is an associative array as well So both types of indexes work on it
      Numeric indexes as well as Keys both work */
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["id"] . " " .
        $row["menu_name"] . " " .
        $row[2] . " " .
        $row[3] . "<hr>";
      }
   ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
   mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Can be served as a good example for databse interaction using php. Nice work.

Comment: OfCourse you need to clear out HTML tags here and use echo to return whatever you want. This is just a very basic sample code for DB interaction. If you understand basic PHP you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some type of server side software to connect to your database.  Javascript and HTML alone won't get you there.  You can make an AJAX request (or a standard POST), but something on the back end has to be there to respond to the request.

Are you running any of the following on your server: ColdFusion, PHP, Python, Ruby, C++, Java, ASP, Perl?

EDIT:

like @showdev suggested, you could use AJAX to post your request to a PHP page which would run an INSERT statement against your database (see @blunderBoy's answer).  Sounds like you have a form on the screen that you are using to enter data, if you use jQuery, your AJAX request might look like this:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize() );
```

where `test.php` is the url that you are posting to, and `testform` is the id of the form where your inputs are located.

Drop that line into your saveData() function where you are appending the row to the table.

Comment: on serverside i'm running php